# Will apps designed for ios 8.1 automatically work on ios 8.2?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Sorry if this seems like a basic question, but I cant seem to find any info about this and I am new to developing for ios :\

I tried building a unity project in the new beta xcode 6.1.2 for ios 8.2 and got over 200 errors...
Reverted to xcodde 6.1 for ios 8.1 and everything works fine.

Just wondering, in general if an app is built with a target of ios 8.1 would it have to be rebuilt later on for 8.2 once it comes out, or will it just automatically work on 8.2 devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work. You do not need to rebuild you app in order to support newer OS versions.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, just wanted to ask, would apps built for ios 7 work on ios 8 as well?

Comment: It is likely that they would, yes. There is a chance that some incompatibilities may occur due to changes to the API and the system between major iOS releases, which would result in crashes or some unexpected behavior in apps built with older SDKs, so it is better practice to test the app using the beta releases of the new OS, and post an update if necessary. You might want to do that for the release of 8.2 too, but the release of *.2 breaking any app built using *.1 is highly unlikely.